# When Using '/' character in history.pushState, MVC rewrite the URL

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, pushstate

I have an ASP.NET MVC project without any special route (using the default). I'm using `history.pushState` in my project as follow: (Let's say we are in `products` page)

```
history.pushState(null, null, '#/param1/param2');
```

The URL changes to: `www.domain.com/param1/param2`, but I expected this: `www.domain.com/products#/param1/param2`.

Notice that, if I use (for example) `-` character instate of `/`, it works as expected.

There are no `JavaScript` or `C#` errors.

Why is it not working as expected?

Comment: your code working fine at my end and it is redirecting to `http://localhost:52485/home/#/param1/param2` in my case.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC btw. `history.pushState` is strictly between the JavaScript being executed on the **client side** and the browser.

Comment: that's true, I know that code has nothing on server-side and just have effect on client-side, but I'm wondering, when I use that code on simple `html` page, everything is fine, but on a `MVC` page, I have mentioned problem ! (and of course if I use `-`, I didn't get that problem)

Answer (score 0):

Your call seems to work fine on Firefox, Chrome and IE, although I still wouldn't rule out that it's browser-specific.

You should use `history.pushState({}, '', '#/param1/param2');` though.

Actually, you may want to consider not using `history` for hash tags at all, but `location.hash` instead.

You can use it like this:

```
locaction.hash = '/param1/param2'
```

Comment: You right, I know is better that I don't use `#` with `pushState`, but in my case, I don't wanna have an action to handle that `params`. (I think, if I don't use `#`, and user copy the `/param1/param2` and paste in new window, I have to handle that with an action on C# side)

Comment: BTW, I used `{}` instate of 'null', in `pushState`, before posting this question. (same for `''` [emprty-string])